# Can’t start VM with img

Tags: debian, kvm, libvirt

I'm using Debian 11 and libvirt with KVM. Previously, I was able to start VMs with a mounted .img file, but now I'm unable to do so.

I have reinstalled virtualization, redownloaded the .img file, and changed its storage location. However, each time I try to start the VM, it fails with the following error:

"Unable to read CD-ROM (error 005)"

The only recent change I made was renaming my PC using hostnamectl.

Comment: Error 5 is usually "permission denied", ie. whatever user is running the virtualisation cannot read the image file

Comment: I suggest you provide details as to where this image is from and how you launch the VM. By the way, normally you don't mount images before launching VMs from them. Can you clarify what this mount is about?